# beginner's question on java (Quartz) scheduling

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I am looking into a web app that already uses Quartz.
In the web.xml there is:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
  <display-name>Quartz-Init Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

What is the job of this servlet and it's lifecycle?
I understand that it does some intialization for the quartz job scheduling but not exactly sure what.
Since there is no `servlet-mapping` for it, I assume that it is not supposed to handle requests.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QuartzInitializerServlet](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html) starts the Scheduler (typically a [StdScheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/impl/StdScheduler.html)) and its worker threads. The configuration will be loaded from the file `quartz.properties`.

If you are only using one scheduler, you can use [QuartzInitializerListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerListener.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's right, this servlet is not supposed to handle requests, but only for quartz initialization.
In fact, the implementation of the methods doPost and doGet returns an error:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
```